# Score ordinal ranking configuration according to an optimal ranking

Tags: ranking, genetic-algorithms

I have a list of items, each associated with their optimal ranking in the list.
How can I give a score to a given order of the list.

For instance, if I know that the optimal ranking is: 4 3 5 1 2
And the current ranking of my items is 1 2 3 4 5,

Which metric can I use as a fitness metric (or score) in order to give my algorithm an information as to whether the current ranking configuration is close to the optimal ranking or not?

I don't think I can use Discounted Cumulative Gain (DCG) as all of my items are equally important (it's not more important to rank one of the items well rather than another)

Answer (score 2):

You can find several options [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_to_rank#Evaluation_measures)

Common choices include:

- MAP
- DCG
- Spearman Rho & Kendall Tau

which can have varying utility in different settings.